# Sharing class objects between processes in Linux

Tags: linux, class, shared

Is it possible to share Class object in common memory?

I have to share the object of class between two process.

John

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do this.

Look at shared memory, using [shmget(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget).

Be very careful though: never try to do this with a class which has virtual methods. The vtable pointer will cause problems.
The vtable pointer points to a table of function pointers, one for each virtual method of the class. There is no guarantee that these pointers will be correct for both processes, meaning that if the wrong process tries to call one of those methods it dereferences an invalid pointer.

Comment: `shmget` is often considered a legacy interface. The modern POSIX interface is [shm_open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/shm_open.html)